# Javascript slideshow only works for one instance of slideshow on page

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have two slideshows on a page - [cems.uwe.ac.uk/~s3-gupta/starterpack/wireless.php](http://cems.uwe.ac.uk/~s3-gupta/starterpack/wireless.php) - one under the "Eduroam with Windows" link, and one under "Eduroam on Mac" link. The second one (mac) doesn't work - instead, it loads the images at the end of the first slideshow. I am going to need to put several more slideshows on this page, and others. Is there any way of making the slideshow work seperately for more than one instance on the page - so I can have multiple seperate slide shows?

the jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bud7u/

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var currentPosition = 0;
        var slideWidth = 560;
        var slides = $('.slide');
        var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

        // Remove scrollbar 
        $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

        // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
         slides
            .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
            // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
            .css({
            'float' : 'left',
            'width' : slideWidth
         });

        // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
         $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

        // Insert controls in the DOM
         $('#slideshow')
          .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
          .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');

        // Hide left arrow control on first load
        manageControls(currentPosition);

      // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
      $('.control')
        .bind('click', function(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

        // Hide / show controls
         manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
        });
    });

     // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
     function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
     if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
     }  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So i've worked out that its because I am using an id instead of a class for the slideshow, and so now I will try and work out if I can use classes instead and still have it work.

Comment: classes broke the whole thing, but i may have done it slightly wrong.... any ideas?!